# Joomla! Rewrite dynamic URL

Tags: php, joomla, url-rewriting, joomla-extensions

I am working in a component to **Joomla! 3** but I am having a litle issue.

**I have this:** `$primary_link->setUrl(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_sweetmail&task=item&item_id=' . $item->getId(), false));` that creates URL something like: `http:://www.mysite.com/component/sweetmail/item/example`.

What I am trying to do is rewrite JRoute dynamically, to delete `/component/sweetmmail/item`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a router.php for the sweetmail component. Currently you don't have one. Check the router.php under the com_banners component to see how it's done. Essentially you will need to to create and to parse the URL. Not that complicated.